# AMP Script to limit Journey Builder Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, journeybuilder

We are about to start warming up our dedicated IPs, I created a journey that will send messages when a lead is created and a decision split based on email domain. Is there a way to limit sends on the Journey? I don't want it to go over 20,000 sends per domain a day.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the entry point? Is it based on automation, event, etc?

Comment: Data Extension Hourly Run

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
Found an Alternate solution that may also work and is even easier.

1. Create a DE from Domain Suppression (DS) template
2. Create SQL (like below) to add the domain name to DS DE if count > 20000 (Action must be overwrite)
3. Set a Domain Exclusion DE inside of the email send in Journey Builder which will dynamically exclude certain domains based on the query from #2.

Just know that these will not be rerun in your Journey (will never get that email), but will continue to the next step.

---

Your best bet would be to have all the leads go into a DE and then use a newly created DE to house total sent per domain. Then use SQL to push this data via OVERWRITE into your Entry DE. This SQL would look at the count DE and if the domain is greater than 20000 for the day, then it won't push them to the send DE.

Quick overview:

**DE 1: Collection DE**

yourPrimaryKey(s) | yourRequireFields | Domain | Sent

Domain - To reference for DE 2

Sent - To determine if the row has already been processed

**DE 2: Domain Count DE**

Domain (primary Key) | Count

Domain - Key for reference of Domain in filter

 Count - total number emails sent to that domain so far

**DE 3: Your sending DE**

There are no special fields needed here. Just use what you need.

---

**Query 1: Total Sent**

Something like `SELECT Domain, COUNT(*) as Count FROM SendLog GROUP BY Domain` if you use a Send Log.  If you do not, you will need to use the [Sent Dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) - which will slow your performance.

**Query 2: Move Collection DE records to Sending DE**
`SELECT cde.yourFields FROM CollectionDE cde WHERE cde.Domain NOT IN (SELECT Domain FROM DomainCountDE WHERE Count < 20000)` (I am sure there are more efficient ways to write it, but this is quick example)

---

**Email Send**

Inside of your email you would need to put some AMPScript to add in the 'Sent' field of the Collection DE so that we know it was already processed.

e.g. `UPSERTDE(collectionDE, yourPrimaryKeys, @yourPrimaryKeyValues, "Sent", "Y")`

You would then just have your Sending DE be the one attached to the journey and this will filter out all the already sent ones and it will also stop sending to domains once they reach 20000.  You would just need to make sure these queries run hourly prior to your entry source.

There are better solutions to this, but they would require more development. Such as utilizing API Entry events, creating AMPScript or SSJS app via Script Activities, etc. That may be more elegant and comprehensive. But this is one of the simplest ways to implement without altering much of what you already have built.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! Would it be possible to replicate this type of process using Journey Builder Data and an Exclusion Script?

Comment: To an extent, but realize that if excluded, like in my edit, the subscriber would never get that email unless rerun through the whole journey again.

Comment: The original solution will retain the sub back until it will be sent, ensuring all your subs will receive the email - some may just be delayed a day or two before injected